Let $g,g_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g_n\to g$ uniformly where g is bounded. Prove that after some $n_0$ , every $g_n(x)$ is bounded
My attempt: Let $g,g_n:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $g_n\to g$ uniformly where g is bounded. Prove there are $M>0,n_o\in\mathbb{N}:\forall\ x\in X,\forall\ n\geq\ n_0\implies\ |g_n(x)|<M$.
Since $g_n\to g$ uniformly, $\forall\ ε>0,\exists\ n_0$ such that $|g_n(x)-g(x)|<ε$ for $n\geq\ n_0$. Then $|g_n(x)|\le|g_n(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|\rightarrow0+|g(x)|$
So $M=|g(x)|+1<\infty$.

Looks like you set $\varepsilon=1$ as one usually does in this kind of problem. Let $N$ be an upper bound for $|g(x)|$, then your calculation shows $M=1+N$ is an upper bound for all the $g_n$ with $n\geq n_0$. Note $M$ cannot depend on $x$, hence you need to introduce an upper bound for $g$ explicitly. You might find it useful to indicate that the $n_0$ should work for all $x$.

Your argument is correct up to and including the use of the triangle inequality:
$$\forall x:|g_n(x)|\leq|g_n(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|$$
After that there is no need to invoke the convergence a second time: just replace $|g_n(x)-g(x)|$ with the upper bound $\varepsilon$ that you have already found (you can pick $\varepsilon=1$) and replace $|g(x)|$ with $\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|g(t)|$ which is a finite number by the hypothesis that $g$ is a bounded function. Now you have a finite upper bound for all $|g_n(x)|$ that does not depend on $x,$ and therefore $g_n$ is bounded. As a bonus you get that the upper bound does not depend on $n\geq n_0$ but that was not required.
